# Google Cloud Storage Budget Limit

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Does Google Cloud Storage allow setting a monthly budget limit, similar to the one available for Google App Engine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage does not implement usage limits on the XML API or for HTTP GETs of public objects.

It is possible to enable access logs: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesslogs
This would give you detailed logs of all access to your objects. You could monitor the logs, and if the usage is higher than you want to allow, change the ACL on your objects to disable further access.